# Casting a byte to Hex

Tags: java, casting

I recieved this question:

[image]

The answer was ffffff80,
but I didn't understand how they got to it..
Why does casting to integer invokes the 2's complement?

Comment: What do you mean by the answer? Code prints 3 lines.

Comment: The CPU uses 2's complement for it's calculations and Java just provides a more friendly way to use those calculations.

Answer (score 1):

```
a: 0x11 -> 17(dec) -> 10001 -> bitshift by 7 -> 100010000000 -> 0x880 -> 2176(dec)
b: (byte) a -> 10000000 -> 0x80 -> 128(dec)
c: (char) b -> char is signed, byte is unsigned -> 0x80 -> -128(dec)
```